# Omniauth Callback for permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Maybe this is a simple question, but I have  rails 4 app using omniauth and devise and I can't figure out how to set a route for the failure to authenticate a user specifically on permission denied. How would I do this? I need to send permission denials to a specific place in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
if user.persisted?
 flash[:notice] = "You are in..!!!"
 sign_in_and_redirect(user)
else
 session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
 redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end

def failure
  #handle you logic here..
  redirect_to root_path 
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume they got the info from something like Facebook? And the user didn't click cancel when it asked for permission?

Comment: When a user clicks sign in via Facebook on my site, they are brought to facebook and it asks: "app will receive the following info: your public profile and email address". If they click "cancel" (to decline giving it info), I need to send them to a specific action. It looks like omniauth has some default behavior, but I would like to override that.

Comment: I think , you need to add failure method in your omniauth callback controller and define your customized behavior. I updated my answer. please have a look. @Red

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [Omniauth-facebook cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526408/omniauth-facebook-cancel-button) answer.

It states that you need add a failure method in your omniauth controller